# Spring Boot's baner and log4j apears in console

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, logback, executable-jar

I have Spring Boot application which internally uses libraries with log4j logging.

I added inside pom.xml (to attach log4j entries to my logback logs):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

According http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging-fileonly I added custom logback-spring.xml which should disable console log output:

```
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

The problem is after:

```
java -jar my-app.jar &
```

baner.txt and following warning are still written to console:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (package.hidden).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Q1: How to disable console logs entirely?
Q2: How to attach log4j log to logback file output?

Comment: Ok, I excluded log4j from my library, and warning does not show. But baner is still visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment, just 1 question left. If you need to disable banner, there are a number of ways. You can do it via `application.properties` file like:

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
```

Or via `application.yml` as:

```
spring:
    main:
        banner-mode: "off"
```

Or even in your sources:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(SomeSpringConfiguration.class);
    application.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
    application.run(args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution to log4j WARN was to exclude transitive dependencies from my internal libraries.

Banner is written to console by default, so we have to set:

```
spring.main.banner-mode=log
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4001